# Python Pandas Add Tuple/List to Cell

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

I'm struggling with setting a cell value to a tuple or list with pandas using .replace()

Here is my dictionary:

```
to_replace = {0: (0.6509803921568628, 0.807843137254902, 0.8901960784313725, 1.0), 
              1: (0.12156862745098039, 0.47058823529411764, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0), 
              2: (0.6980392156862745, 0.8745098039215686, 0.5411764705882353, 1.0)}
```

Here is my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ArrayID': {3: 'C112216_S47', 2: 'H9_S73', 1: 'NI_ADULT_S72', 0: 'org_H14_Colon_p13_S1'}, 
              'Category': {3: 'C112216_S47', 2: 'H9_S73', 1: 'NI_ADULT_S72', 0: 'org_H14_Colon_p13_S1'}, 
              'cval': {3: 2, 2: 0, 1: 1, 0: 0}})
```

And here is my attempt to add a new column "color" with each tuple above:

```
df["color"] = df["cval"].replace(to_replace)
```

The output I'd like is

```
                ArrayID              Category  cval     color
3           C112216_S47           C112216_S47     2  (0.6980392156862745, 0.8745098039215686, 0.5411764705882353, 1.0)
2                H9_S73                H9_S73     0  (0.6509803921568628, 0.807843137254902, 0.8901960784313725, 1.0)
1          NI_ADULT_S72          NI_ADULT_S72     1  (0.12156862745098039, 0.47058823529411764, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0)
0  org_H14_Colon_p13_S1  org_H14_Colon_p13_S1     0  (0.6509803921568628, 0.807843137254902, 0.8901960784313725, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `replace`:

```
df["color"] = df["cval"].map(to_replace)
```

Output:

```
                ArrayID              Category  cval                                                                color
3           C112216_S47           C112216_S47     2    (0.6980392156862745, 0.8745098039215686, 0.5411764705882353, 1.0)
2                H9_S73                H9_S73     0     (0.6509803921568628, 0.807843137254902, 0.8901960784313725, 1.0)
1          NI_ADULT_S72          NI_ADULT_S72     1  (0.12156862745098039, 0.47058823529411764, 0.7058823529411765, 1.0)
0  org_H14_Colon_p13_S1  org_H14_Colon_p13_S1     0     (0.6509803921568628, 0.807843137254902, 0.8901960784313725, 1.0)
```